# Converting String to java bean type

Tags: java, spring

I have a string which looks like this and it represents a pojo.

```
Model [Name=Mobie , location= US, actualTransferDate=null, scanserialCode=234335,1237787, modelNum=MIC 898989 ]
```

I want bit clearer to reader on the above string. I want to read the user checked checkbox values(represents entire row with the fileds in below pojo) in an jsp page table to another jsp page. So, in the controller i read these checked checkbox rows as bellow.

```
String[] checkeditems = request.getParameterValues("case");//case represents the entire row
    for (String string : checkeditems) {
        log.info("row1"+string);// String pasted above in the message
    }
```

From the above it returns as a string Array which i want convert to be as a list object, so that i can easily send this list to next jsp for a view. I feel i am heading to wrong direction and doing some unrelated stuff.

I have a pojo as

```
public class Model{
private String Name;
private String location;
private String actualTransferDate;
private String scanserialCode;
private String modelNum;
====Getters/Setter======
```

How i can convert this String to this model object?

Comment: Can you point any example or bit more write help to understand on this?

Answer (score 1):

you can split the string on ", " and iterate over the result array. With [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) from apache can you fill your new pojo instance.

**Example:**

```
public class Model {
    private String Name;
    private String location;
    private String actualTransferDate;
    private String scanserialCode;
    private String modelNum;
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getActualTransferDate() {
        return actualTransferDate;
    }
    public void setActualTransferDate(String actualTransferDate) {
        this.actualTransferDate = actualTransferDate;
    }
    public String getScanserialCode() {
        return scanserialCode;
    }
    public void setScanserialCode(String scanserialCode) {
        this.scanserialCode = scanserialCode;
    }
    public String getModelNum() {
        return modelNum;
    }
    public void setModelNum(String modelNum) {
        this.modelNum = modelNum;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Name = " + getName() + "location = " +getLocation() + ", actualTransferDate = " + getActualTransferDate() + ", scanserialCode = " + getScanserialCode() + ", modelNum = " + getModelNum() + "]";
    }
}


import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        String model = new String("Name=Mobie , location= US, actualTransferDate=null, scanserialCode=234335,1237787, modelNum=MIC 898989");

        String[] modelValues = model.split(", ");

        Model m = new Model();

        for (String value : modelValues) {
            String[] s = value.split("=");

            String fieldName = s[0];
            String fieldValue = s[1];

            BeanUtils.setProperty(m, fieldName, fieldValue);
        }

        System.out.println(m.toString());
    }
}
```

**Maven dependency:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it completely dynamic, you can use Reflection.

For example, use a regular expression (Pattern/Matcher) to find the [ ... ] part, use the String before that as a class name (assuming you know the package name) and then do a simple comma/equals-sign split in the [ ... ] part and fill the fields via reflection... Not that hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constructor in the Model class which accepts the full string as input. The use StringTokenizer with delimiter as ',' to convert the string to a list of tokens. Then tokenizer each token with '='as the delimiter. This way you will have all the members of Model class tokens which can be used to initialize the values of the member variables.